# Python speech Client error: Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED)

Tags: python, grpc, google-cloud-speech

I am a newbie in Google Speech API and I want to use it. Below is what I have done till now.
1. I have installed google cloud speech in Windows

2. I am running behind corporate proxy so I have added the proxy in environment variable HTTP_PROXY and GPRC_PROXY_EXP
3. I am trying the example https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python.
4. When I encounter **response = client.recognize(config, audio)**, I get the following error -
5. google.gax.errors.RetryError: RetryError(Retry total timeout exceeded with exception, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, Deadline Exceeded)>)

Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using the sample transcribe_async.py. If yes then you need to increase the wait time-out for response from async call. It depends on the duration of your audio file, may be from 90 to say 250 (?)

response = operation.result(timeout=90)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vinay. But I am getting the error before that i.e. when I run the command response = client.recognize(config, audio). This is from the example quickstart.py

Comment: Hi Shreeram, you are supposed to get this output: `Transcript: how old is the Brooklyn Bridge`. Does it wait for a long time before throwing up this error? if you are getting timeout error on `python quickstart.py` then you are not able to reach the google cloud. Check your internet connection or any other firewall settings.

Comment: Yes Vinay it does wait for a long time before throwing out the error. I am running this on my company's network and I cannot change the firewall settings as I do not have admin access

Comment: As a simple test please run this command on terminal: `ping speech.googleapis.com` and check if its reachable. If you get relevant response then check if port 443 is blocked in your organization.

Comment: So here is the thing, I am not able to reach speech.googleapis.com. But I had done a simple test before and here is what I did -

Comment: 1. Created a service account in google cloud and downloaded the key file in json format

2. Ran gcloud init and set the deafult project and service account as my login

3. Ran gcloud auth activate-service-account iamserviceaccount --key-file=\path\to\json

4. gcloud auth --account iamserviceaccount print-access-token
output = accesstoken to use it with curl command

5. curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: \path\to\json" -H "Authorization: Bearer access-token(4)" https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize -d @sync-request.json